# problems printing

Tags: printing

I am running ubuntu 14.04, and am having problem printing.   When I print from evince,
I get the error message:

```
Internal Error: cairo context error: invalid matrix (not invertible)<0a>
Internal Error: cairo context error: invalid matrix (not invertible)<0a>
Internal Error: cairo context error: invalid matrix (not invertible)<0a>
```

I've tried deleting the printer and reinstalling the printer, and deleting cups and
reinstalling cups, but nothing seems to help.

I have a HP laserjet 1022 printer.

Comment: This is likely just a  bug with evince, which can be [reported](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) to them and fixed. If you have problems printing with other PDF programs (e.g. [Okular](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/okular/)), you can add relevant info to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are facing this issue with pdf file printing. Similar issue has been reported and fixed. Please check the link below for further details.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poppler/+bug/276837

Comment: Managed to fix the problem myself.   Problem was in the .config/evince/print-settings file.   Replaced it with a fresh file from a new user to resolve problem.

Comment: @SamEvens Can you add that as an answer below? Thanks!